# For some reason part of this PHP code is being commented out

Tags: php, comments

I was trying to get this code to run but for some reason chrome comments the code out. It seems to be correct syntax to me and one other person.

```
<div>
                <?php
                    $msg_id = '103'; //Message id
                    $uid = '1'; // Message user id
                    $q = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT like_id FROM message_like WHERE uid_fk='$uid' and msg_id_fk='$msg_id'");
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($q) === 0) {
                        echo '<a href="#" class="like" id="like'. $msg_id . '" title="Unlike" rel="Unlike">Unlike</a>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href="#" class="like" id="like'. $msg_id . '" title="Like" rel="Like">Like</a>';
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Because PHP doesn't run in the browser?

Comment: Your PHP will be invisible in all browsers, not just Chrome....if you do not see the echoed output when you "View Source" then something is wrong

Comment: Make sure the filename suffix is `.php`. If it is, check your webserver configuration and make sure it has PHP enabled for .php files.

Comment: what is the output you are getting @ chrome?

Comment: I know PHP doesn't actually run in the browser but I mean it appears as a comment in the browser... http://d.pr/i/mnJD (screenshot) http://d.pr/i/nAFc

Comment: That's what I mean. haha

Comment: You have an error in your code and the string was broken....check your error log for a parse error

Comment: In the browser, if you do a 'View Source', does the part that says `<?php` look more like `&lt;?php`?? If that's the case, then you're characters are being HTML Encoded

Answer (score 1):

You are asking why the browser, a client-side application, is commenting out PHP, a server-side language. You need to install a server like Apache or nginx. If you are a total beginner, try the XAMPP project to get a server on your desktop. XAMPP is cross-platform, so it will run on your OS.

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: Well I mean that is exactly the program I am using just that for some reason there is an error that I am not seeing.

Comment: Some other questions then: was it not an un-closed string issue, like @ChemistryBlob mentioned? Also, are you editing the files directly inside of a text editor, or are you using some web interface to upload the PHP? In other words, what's the context where you're editing?